# creating new text with multiplier chars using functions

Tags: python, function, char

I want to create new string based on string given by user, but every char in the string have to be multiplied by number also given by user. How to do it the correct way?

```
def get_text(message: str) -> str:
    return input(f'{message}')


def get_multiplier(number: str) -> int:
    return int(input(f'{number}:\n'))


def get_multiplied_text(message: str, number: str) -> list:
    new_message = []
    



def main() -> None:
    message = get_text('get text')
    multiplier = get_multiplier('get multiplier')
    print(message)
    print(multiplier)
```

i tried to do it by list and list comprehension

Comment: Many answerers use tags to filter content. A programming language is an important one; you might want to add [tag:python].

Comment: kindly add your desired output, it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension is one correct way to do it, it's concise and easy to understand:

```py
def get_multiplied_text(message: str, number: str) -> list:
    return [c * number for c in message]
```

If you want to return a string:

```py
def get_multiplied_text(message: str, number: str) -> str:
    return ''.join([c * number for c in message])
```

Alternatively, you can pass a generator expression to `join` instead of the list comprehension:

```py
def get_multiplied_text(message: str, number: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(c * number for c in message)
```

Comment: `[...]` is unnecessary in the second snippet, since `join` can take a generator.

Comment: @Amadan, there are use-cases where `[...]` is faster than the generator, because CPython can pre-allocate an empty list and just insert items at positions. If you use a generator, you follow the regular grow-and-insert flow. Less important in this case, but worth keeping in mind ;)